# apache server mod_expire usage

Tags: apache, tcpdump, mod-expires

I am using Apache 2.2.20. I set the `expire_mod` to be "access plus 5 minutes". I check the header using some website, and I am sure that in the header there did has an expire directory.
However, when I use a tcpdump to monitor the network traffic, I still see the packet transfer when I reload the webpage using the Firefox, which should not be expired. Does anyone know the reason for this? Thanks.

Comment: Show the configuration, show us the headers returned by Apache for an URL you think should trigger your mod_expires directives

Comment: header returned:HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Wed, 21 Dec 2011 20:19:36 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.20 (Unix) DAV/2 Cache-Control: max-age=300 Expires: Wed, 21 Dec 2011 20:24:36 GMT Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8

Comment: I added the following line to the config file.<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 minutes"
</IfModule>

Comment: OK, so your server is configured correctly (`Cache-Control` is present)

Answer (score 2):

When you hit the "reload" button of your browser, the browser assumes that it should try and reload all elements of the page.

You have mod_expires configured correctly. However, this won't stop the browser trying: when you hit the reload button, a request for each element will be sent anyway, with a `If-Modified-Since` header, but since, on the Apache side, it hasn't been modified, Apache will return a `304 Not modified`.

So, you *do* see traffic, just not a full page reload. You can witness this with the same tool you used to capture the headers to confirm keepalive is working (and by the way, a 5 minutes max-age is low).